# Syntax error near like phrases, sql, selecting function

Tags: python, sql

My code is:

```
sql_command='''SELECT Grade FROM GRADES where Student_number='''+str(id)
sql_command+=''' And Course_ID LIKE'''+Course_code
```

where the Course_code is a given parameter. So basically I am selecting grades on 2 conditions.
One is the student number equals to the id given, and Course ID starts with the Course_code given. 
For example, the Course id is 'psyc11', the course code is 'psy'.

Comment: You are missing a space after `LIKE`.  Whatever SQL database API you are using in Python likely has a means of binding these values as parameters, injection safe and preferred over concatenation.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski thx, the course_code is psy, and course_id column is psyc11. it says no such psy column.

Comment: Because those are strings and strings need to be single quoted in SQL statements. What RDBMS are you using and what python module are you using to query it? These problems are solved by using its parameterization mechanism properly. (your description of the error message vaguely suggests maybe MySQL)

Comment: @Michael Berkowski yes. and how should i do the parameterization properly?

Comment: That can't be answered without knowing the other things I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the second argument to LIKE in quotes, hence:

```
sql_command = "SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE Student_number = " + str(id) +
              " AND Course_ID LIKE " + Course_code + "*'"
```

I've chosen to use double quotes around segments to simplify embedding single quotes.

You could also consider:

```
sql_command = "SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE Student_number = %d AND Course_ID LIKE '%s*'" % (id, Course_code)
```

Given:

```
Course_code = 'psy'
ID = 2334
```

both yield:

```
SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE Student_number = 2334 AND Course_ID LIKE 'psy*'
```